# Excel - Finding a name then inserting a specific value

Tags: excel

Alright guys, I do not know exactly how to phrase this question but I have a picture and an example of exactly what I am trying to do.

***Here is my excel sheet screenshot:***
[image]

So I have a list of players, their points and a space for their team name.
I have a team already listed in `E1:E5`, there will be more teams defined in `F1:F5` and so on... There are a lot of players in this sheet and the order of them are scrambled.

Instead of manually finding each player and typing in their team name, I wish to just type in the team name and its players into a block and have column A automatically update with the corresponding team name. I tried to fiddle around with `VLOOKUP` and `=Index(match())` to no avail. Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you are going for?  It seems like you need to do a vlookup referencing a set of clean data.  From the image I cant quite see what result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Formula in A2:

```
=INDEX($E$1:$G$1,1,SUMPRODUCT(($E$2:$G$5=B2)*(COLUMN($E$1:$G$1)-4)))
```

`($E$2:$G$5=B2)` is like a full array lookup, returns an array of true and false

`(COLUMN($E$1:$G$1)-4)` gives an array containing the column numbers. `-4` because E is column 5, so that the first team, `Optic` becomes column number 1 after subtracting 4, TeamB becomes column number 2 (column 6 - 4), etc

`SUMPRODUCT(($E$2:$G$5=B2)*(COLUMN($E$1:$G$1)-4))` thus gives the column number in which the match was found.

**Note:** this formula will not work properly if there are more than 1 match, and will return `#VALUE` when no match is found.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much man!

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable with Match and Index and Offset and Indirect like this: (assumes unique player names)

in a single column enter your team name and then under the team name

In, say C1 and down from there:

Blue Team
John Smith
Mary Farmer
David Johns

Red Team
Alfred Peterson
Jacob Enders
Joan Summers

Now, to the cells to the right of the names, put their offset from the team: next to John put 1, David, 3, ALfred, 1 etc.

Now the formula, broken into three cells to explain it:

cell 1 - at F1: The reference name - "Jacob Enders"

cell 2 - at F2: `=MATCH(F1,C:C,0)`

cell 3 - at F3: `=INDEX(D:D,F2)`

cell 4 - at F4: `=OFFSET(INDIRECT("C"&F2,TRUE),-F3,0)`

You should be right from there